# Invertibility of a Matrix. Completion of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N_{1}\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times\left(  n-m\right)  }$ and $N_{2}\in
\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ such that $rank\left(  \left(  N_{1},N_{2}\right)
\right)  =m$. Is it possible to find matrices $M_{1}\in\mathbb{R}^{\left(
n-m\right)  \times\left(  n-m\right)  }$ and $M_{2}\in R^{\left(  n-m\right)
\times m}$ such that $rank\left(  M_{1}\right)  =n-m$ and $rank\left(
\begin{array}
[c]{cc}%
M_{1} & M_{2}\\
N_{1} & N_{2}%
\end{array}
\right)  =n$?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking basically whether an independent set of vectors in a finite dimensional vector space (in this case, the rows of $(N_1, N_2)$) can be completed to a basis. The answer is always yes. The side condition that $\mathop{rank}(M_1) = n-m$ is easy to assure by making $M_1$ to be a large multiple of the identity.

Comment: My question is not whether a family of vectors linearly independent could be completed to constitute a basis; this is very obvious from Algebra. The question is whether it is possible to do that under the assumption that $M_{1}$ is full-ranked. Note that the fact that a set of vectors living in
$\mathbf{R}^{n}$ is linearly independent does not imply that the projection onto $\mathbf{R}^{m}$ is linearly independent (the converse is true).